# "making a total of" or "totalizing"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction

I would like to know if I should use **making a total of** or **totalizing** to express a sum of elements such as in the following sentence:

> The study included 30 hospitals and 3 clinics. For ease of
>   communication, the 3 clinics will henceforth be regarded as hospitals, **making a total of** / **totalizing** 33 hospitals.

Comment: Personally I think ***totalizing*** here is just inappropriate use of jargon. But with *...regarded as **one** of the hospitals* it doesn't make sense anyway (that approach would lead me to expect a total of ***31*** hospitals, not 33).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FumbleFingers. You are wright. "regarded as one of the hospitals" doesn't make sense. I've rewrote the sentence. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yeah, that's better. But as to the substance of your question as now revised, if each clinic is to be counted as a hospital anyway, I honestly can't see why you'd risk insulting your reader by implying he needs your help to add 30 and 3 together. At least with the original phrasing (if the final total were changed to 31) you could justify it on the grounds that you're clarifying the effect of the analytical approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### "Making a total of" is acceptable, but a little verbose.

Your other option uses a similar looking verb that has an incorrect meaning. *Totalize* means⁰  "*to comprehend* in a way that includes everything" but you intend to convey "amounts to a sum of" which would be "totaling." So your sentence would best be written:

> The study included 30 hospitals and 3 clinics. For ease of communication, the 3 clinics will henceforth be regarded as hospitals, **totaling** 33 hospitals.

---

⁰Commenters have suggested that, in some places, *totalize* can indeed mean "amounts to a sum of." This may be true but using it in this way risks confusing readers who understand its meaning only as I have indicated. So, even if it's technically acceptable for some, it is best not to use it in this way.

Comment: I too have only heard *totalizing* used in the way you describe, but apparently dictionaries do include definitions of *totalize* with the meaning "to total."

Comment: I agree with this answer-- As a US English speaker, I've always heard totalize to mean comprehend broadly, and totalizing to mean comprehensive (as in a "totalizing world view").  I have never seen "to totalize" to mean "to add up to." For that, I've always seen "to total."

Comment: @juh Good to know! I've gone ahead and added a note to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think "totalizing" is the best choice here, though I don't think I would use either of those. Instead, I would use "totaling" or "for a total of":

> ... the 3 clinics will henceforth be regarded as hospitals, **for** a total of 33 hospitals.
>
> ... the 3 clinics will henceforth be regarded as hospitals, **totaling** 33 hospitals.

I don't think "totalizing" is grammatically incorrect (it's a [word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/totalize), after all), but it's not commonly used in my experience.